# Extract Song Information from Embedded Mp3 file, ID3 classes

Tags: blackberry, mp3, id3-tag

I am building an application whereby streams live online radio, everything is working fine.

I just need a few tips on how to extract the song information from the embedded mp3 file and display it on the application i.e now playing with the song information.

I have done my research on ID3 but didn't find any good resource. can anyone help out please

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this web-site](http://www.id3.org/Developer_Information) for the ID3 format specification.

ID3 information specified in the header of mp3 file, read the header, parse it and voila, you have the ID3 information on the playing song.

Comment: Thanks for linking to an actual spec.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the language you are using but if you are using Java here's a free library that do what you need to do

http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

Does this helps? Or provide more details about platform and language.

Comment: i am using Eclipse platform and java language, ive downloaded the jar file and i will check if it works now,i will keep you posted thanks

Comment: but there has to be some sort of way i will link it to the page i want it to be on because only attaching the jar file wouldnt really make a difference?

Comment: Excuse me, can you be a little more clear on your second comment. My english is not enough good to understand what you're trying to say about the "page".

Comment: i mean, it is a jar file,i have to reference it from my application to the page i want it to display on i.e the playerscreen page?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you mean when you say Page. Are you using some J2EE web container? JSP, JSF or something like that? In that case you should have an stateless utility bean that you connect to your page to provide the extraction operations.

Comment: i am using this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255 to build my application whereby has a start up page(splashscreen) which goes into the playerscreen page where the streaming functions are i.e play stop etc,on this page is what i will like to display the information? ... also in the .jar libary there are different .java files which one should i use please?

Answer (score 0):

I've just started to use the Python library eyeD3 - very powerful, very well structured, and come with a nice set of command line tools too.